# alterando client_max_body_size: nginx + beanstalk

Tags: nginx, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying the upload limit imposed by NGINX...

I created a proxy.conf file that has:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        http {
          client_max_body_size 50M;
        }
```

in the `.platform/nginx/conf.d` folder structure.

I deployed the code and I keep getting the error: `413 Request Entity Too Large`